# How to make a DIV fill the whole screen after page loading

Tags: css, html

We are making a website for the TEDx in our city and we're stuck..

Here's a draft copy of it: tedx.mozerov.ru

We have a div id="section-event" which we want to be for the whole page on loading. We added the height:100%; and width:100%;, but the block is still does not fill the whole page :(

Please help!

Comment: The solution of adding 
position:absolute;
top:0;left:0; definitely helps, but! It definitely fills the screen in the way we want it to do, but now the nextcoming divs are coming on top of the desired one :(
Does it have to do anything with the absolute positioning? Because when I make the position:realtive; the div does not fill the whole screen, but the nextcoming divs are ok. Here's the example: tedx.mozerov.ru

Comment: Ok! We found a solution! We add position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%; to the body tag and then our div gets on the whole screen without positioning attribute :) just height:100% and width:100%.

Comment: Thanks to all who participated!

Answer (score 15):

Well, not sure how you are going to use this div, but:

```
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;
```

Comment: Your answer should work though based on the info given, but note that this will only fill the page if the div isn't a child of another tag that's positioned relative or absolute with a defined width/height smaller than the page's width/height.

Comment: This solution uses absolute positioning which removes element from the natural document flow. How can this be achieved with static positioning?

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot comment on other people's answers so here is my answer and it's only a simple addition to uotonyh's that may work.

Make the position absolute and add an arbitrary z-index. As long as the z-index is higher than the other absolute/relative DIVs, then it should take up the entire viewport. If you see a space on the top and left side, then add margin: 0px; to your body css tag.

Ex.

```
#section-event {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply height:100% to both the html and body elements.
I just tested in FireBug and I think it achieves the effect you want.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. I just tested that too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your website layout, sometimes you have incompatibilities. But in general something like this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvtk/

```
#redoverlay {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I've seen this being used in some sites where the `<div id="redoverlay"></div>` element exists at all times, but is with its visibility disabled. When its needed its set to visible by JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

What you probably need is `margin: 0px` in `body`

http://jsfiddle.net/pVNhU/